# Error 5489 - "NOTHING FOUND FOR REQUESTED CRITERIA"

Tags: amadeus

Sometimes I receive 5489 - "NOTHING FOUND FOR REQUESTED CRITERIA" from Amadeus API when requesting offers

Can you explain in more detail what the problem could be? Is it something with the format of the date, with the number of guests, or something else?

The test query set for receive 5489 error:

```
amadeusHotelId: ZWLON008 
adults: 2 
checkInDate: 2022-02-20
checkOutDate: 2022-02-21
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that no hotels are found that match your search criteria. If you are using the free test environment of Amadeus for Developers, keep in mind that you get access to a limited [collection of data](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/test-environment-data-collection-746).